# Valgrind massif tool reporting same snapshots

Tags: linux, memory, valgrind, massif

I need to run valgrind with the massif tool in a parallel code that takes a long time to finish.
I want to take snapshots periodically.

I do the following:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file=outFile.txt --vgdb=yes ./app
```

And in another terminal, I run a loop with the following:

```
vgdb all_snapshot snapshots.txt
```

Yet, "snapshots.txt" has always the same content. I tried with different valgrind options such as --time-unit=ms and --time-unit=i.
And, if I get all the snapshots at moment X of execution and then at moment X+Y, the two generated files are identical.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: massif doesn't write its output until shutdown. If you're looking the file while valgrind is running, you're looking at contents from the previous run, and it won't change until the current run ends.

Comment: Then, what the vgdb does? https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-commandhandling  I don't think valgrind somehow stores the information across different runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

massif has a logic to store in memory a set of snapshots. The number of snaphots and when to take them is controlled by various options such as --peak-inaccuracy, --max-snapshots, ...

Depending on the behaviour of your application between two moments, new snapshots might or might not have been recorded.

The monitor command 'all_snapshots' just saves the snapshots currently in memory.

If you want to force a new snapshot to be output, use the monitor commands 'snapshot' or 'detailed_snapshot'.